# Does "how weight is it" equal to "What weight is it"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Does "how weight is it" equal to "What weight is it"?

When I want to ask about something (e.g. egg) what is its weight, I have other options such as:

> "**How** weight is it"
>
> "**What** weight is it"

Googling shows results to both of them, should I conclude that they are both correct?

In addition, I'd like to know what is the way to ask a person (as a caregiver) about his weight. (these are the options that I thought about, but I'm not sure: what is your weight? How weight are you? How weight you are? what weight are you?)

Comment: Just because Google searches show a result for something does not mean it is correct.

Comment: If you are going to mention Google searches, add some such usage (full sentences) with links. Searching on only a few words is not accurate. We can't guess what you saw.

Comment: "How heavy is it?" or "How much does it weigh?" are normal usages.  To me, if talking to a person, "How much do you weigh?" is more polite than the other options

Comment: *How much does it weigh?* is what is most used in standard American English. For a person, use a personal pronoun, instead (*How much do you weigh?*). You can also say *What is your weight?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ask what something's weight is, you would say (for those examples at least)

> "How much does it weigh?"
>
> "What is its weight?"

Because ***weigh*** in this form is a verb meaning "have a specified weight." you need to use "how much does" as the object is the thing performing the action of weighing something. ***Weight*** is a noun meaning "a body's relative mass or the quantity of matter contained by it, giving rise to a downward force; the heaviness of a person or thing." and is usually considered a property of the object, which is why you'd use the possessive for that variant of the sentence. You **could** say

> "What weight is it?"

but that's kind of awkward wording and not something a native would usually say. Note also that there is the adjective "weighty" meaning "weighing a great deal; heavy" so you could theoretically say

> "How weighty is it?"

but that usually has the connotation that the thing is probably heavy to begin with.

As a caregiver, the best way for you to ask this question would either be

> "How much do you weigh?"

or

> "How heavy are you?"

Note, though, that the second one may be considered offensive by some people as, again, it carries connotations that you're considering them heavy to begin with.

Edit: As M.M pointed out in the comments, you also have the simpler question "How heavy is it?" which is more commonly used.

Comment: I might not think "How weighty is it?" refers to a weight in kilograms or pounds (_weighty_ isn't wrong, but, most of the time, _heavy_ would be a better word to use). For example, a thin novel can be a weighty novel – if it causes people to think deeply.

Comment: @J.R. Good point that weight doesn't always refer to how much mass something has; upvoted.